# In a cyclic group G, is it necessarily true that $(xy)^a = x^ay^a$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Sorry if I violated any rules: my first post. I'd imagine, that if the inequality above is untrue, it is because we don't know that x and y commute.

Comment: But if you know $G$ is a cyclic group, that's automatically abelian so the group operation does commute.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $(xy)^a$ as $$\underbrace{(xy)(xy)\cdots(xy)}_{\text{$a$ times}}$$ and $x^ay^a$ as $$\underbrace{xx\cdots x}_{\text{$a$ times}} 
\underbrace{yy\cdots y}_{\text{$a$ times}}$$ One is just a "reordering" of the other. Such a reordering is only possible if the group is abelian.

Comment: *because the group is abelian

Answer (score 0):

To see that a cyclic group is as abelian, via your fact, which is equivalent to being abelian, let $g$ be the generator and write elements in terms of powers of $g$. 
$$
x^ay^a=g^{ma}g^{na}=(g^{n}g^{m})^{a}=(xy)^a
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Given that $G$ is cyclic, we can write $$G=\langle g\rangle$$ for some $g\in G$. Choose any two elements $x,y\in G$, then there exist non-negative integers $a,b$ such that $g^a=x, g^b=y$. From this, it follows that $$xy=g^ag^b=g^{a+b}=g^{b+a}=g^bg^a=yx$$